# Android - how to call a method from another class in a broadcaster class?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

In my code I have a java file with this in it:

```
package com.myapp.basic;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Parse the SMS.
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            // Retrieve the SMS.
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                // In case of a particular App / Service.
                //if(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("+91XXX"))
                //{
                //str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                //str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                //}
            }
            if (str != "") { // remove the last \n
                str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
            }

            // Need to find a better way to check if the activity is running
            try {
                ((Police_ViewActivity) context.getApplicationContext()).handle_incoming_help_message(str); // crash here
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ");
        }
    }
}
```

When the code in the try block happens, it crashes and i get this error:
08-27 22:45:11.345: I/System.out(27606): android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.escortme.basic.Police_ViewActivity

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I already explained to you in a previous question that you can't treat an Android `Activity` in the same way as a general Java class. An `Activity` is a UI framework - a `BroadcastReceiver` is a 'listener' for specific events/actions. If you want a `BroadcastReceiver` to work with an `Activity` it should be part of that `Activity`, in other words an inner class of the `Activity`.

Comment: but how do I define it in the manifest it I do that?

Comment: You don't define it in the manifest. Use `registerReceiver(...)` in the `Activity` (normally in `onResume()`). Also use `unregisterReceiver(...)` (normally in `onPause()`) when the `Activity` isn't running.

Comment: can you give a code snippet, this is very confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

Calling Activity is best using `Intent`. You can just put something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Police_ViewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("help_message", str);

context.startActivity(intent);
```

In onResume() of your Police view Activity, grab the extra and handles it:

```
onResume(){
    String msg = getIntent().getStringExtra("help_message");
    if (msg==null) return;
    handleMessage(msg);
}
```

You don't have to worry multiple instance of the Activity being created, in manifest you can specify how the activity launch using [Launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). singleInstance could be your choice.

Comment: how do I get it so only at most one instance of policeview is active?

Comment: also where do I put the top code, because it says constructor intent in undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to call handle_incoming_help_message method in another class, just make handle_incoming_help_message method static.

`update:`

So you should start Police_ViewActivity and tell it that you need to call handle_incoming_help_message

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Police_ViewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
intent.putExtra("handle_incoming_help_message", str);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

and in Police_ViewActivity's onCreate (or onResume or Onstart)

```
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("handle_incoming_help_message");
if(str != null)
    handle_incoming_help_message(str);
```

`Update 2`

To keep the number of instances of policeviewactivity to be at most 1? -> [Android LaunchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

Comment: I can't do that because other methods in the policeview activity require them methods to be non-static.

Comment: how do I keep the number of instances of policeviewactivity to be at most 1?

Comment: also I am getting this error: `08-27 23:30:06.014: I/System.out(28576): Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`